# check if more than 3 students belong to the same class from an array

Tags: php, arrays

i need to check if in an exam that contains 5 students

exist 3 students from the same class.

**here is what i tried**

```
<?
//this array contains all student id's that are in an exam
$exam = array('s1' => $s1, 's2' => $s2, 's3' => $s3, 's4' => $s4, 's5' => $s5);

$values = implode(", ", $exam);

$sql = "SELECT class FROM students WHERE students.id IN (" . $values . ")";

try{
    $db = new db();
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);

    $studs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $db = null;

    if(!empty($studs)) {

        //check if 3 students from the same class are taking the exam   


    } else {  
        echo "error";
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {}
?>
```

**Problem**

what i am not sure about is how to count that 3 students have the same class id in this exam array.

one way i thought i could be done is by placing all classes of each student in the exam in an array and then using `array_count_values` to see if there's any value that is bigger than 3, if that is possible i am not sure how it can be achieved.

Comment: Why are you pulling any rows out of the database?  Why not select a count?

Comment: The students that are taking the exam aren't in the DB already? This sounds like something that should already be in the DB with its own table then you could do a join, if needed (for just a count you wouldn't, for the names you would).

Comment: @Devon cant do it from db, the exam array is send via request through api, i just need to validate that it doesnt contain 3 students in the same class

Comment: But you don't care about the data in the rows, just the number of rows, right?

Comment: @Devon the data from the db is the classes id for each student id in the array

Comment: Let me give you an example query for you to run...  `SELECT class, count(*) FROM student GROUP BY class`

Comment: but this would select all students not only the ones from my exam array, no ?

Comment: Yes....  this was an example of selecting a count.  Work from that example and add your conditions and go from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your table name is `students` it's assumed there is one record per student. If you modify your query slightly you should be able to achieve the result without needing to count your records afterwards:

```
SELECT 
    class
FROM 
    students 
WHERE 
    students.id IN (" . $values . ")
GROUP BY
    class
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 3
;
```

If the query returns nothing you know there are less than 3 students in the same class. Otherwise, you will have the class(es) with 3 or more students.

However, if you want to achieve this with PHP then you will need to keep track of each class and count the student records. Here is an example:

```
if ( ! empty($studs)) {
    // Store the counts per class
    $class_count = array();

    foreach ($studs as $student) {

        // Add to your counter for this class
        if ( ! isset($class_count[$student['class']])) {
            $class_count[$student['class']] = 0;
        }
        $class_count[$student['class']]++;

        // Do something if you have 3 students in the same class
        if ($class_count[$student['class']] >= 3) {

            // take action

        }
    }
}
```

**Also, as a PSA please take a look at the PHP SQL Injection page (http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) to ensure your application is protected.**

Comment: great this is what i needed, my only issue is now i get Undefined offset: on this line `$class_count[$student['class']]++;` if i try echoing `$student` i get Array to string conversion

Comment: Updated example to prevent undefined offset.

Comment: it does not validate that there are more than 3, i tried adding an else and `print_r($class_count)` i got `Array ( [1] => 1 )`, shouldn't count the common class id's from students ?

Comment: You should use either the SQL suggestion or the PHP suggestion - not both. If you only implemented the PHP and that is what you received then that would suggest your original query only returned one result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the count keyword:

$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
echo count($cars);

```
https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_count
```

So you first see what the array holds and then you count how many places hold the same student.id